# Can I use an OR statement to indicate the pattern in stringr's str_extract_all function?

Tags: regex, r

I'm looking at a number of cells in a data frame and am trying to extract any one of several sequences of characters; there's only one of these sequences per per cell.

Here's what I mean:

```
dF$newColumn = str_extract_all(string = "dF$column1", pattern ="sequence_1|sequence_2")
```

Am I screwing the syntax up here? Can I pull this sort of thing with stringr? Please rectify my ignorance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `|` since it denotes logical *or* in regex. Here's an example:

```
vec <- c("abc text", "text abc", "def text", "text def text")
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string = vec, pattern = "abc|def")
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "abc"

[[3]]
[1] "def"

[[4]]
[1] "def"
```

However, in your command, you should replace `"dF$column1"` with `dF$column1` (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks!! Also, glad you showed the whole of the syntax, since I kept enclosing vec within quotes, writing string ="vec". It's way too late.