# R Regular expression to create new categorical variable

Tags: r

Trying to create a new variable in the data frame  based on a column:

```
URL_List <- c("/WX_PaymentTran/Acct/12345","/WY_PaymentTran/Acct/678", "/DL_PaymentDaily/Acct/890") # sample , 100s of URLs
URL_df <- data.frame(URL_List)
URL_df$NewCat <- regexpr("^/.*PaymentTran/.*","CatA",URL_df$URL_List )   
URL_df$NewCat <- regexpr("^/.*PaymentDaily/.*","CatB",URL_df$URL_List  ) # 100s of category
And Want to categories different category where individual regular expression matches
so that the resulting dataframe will have NewCategory "CatA" / "CatB", / "CatC" ....
```

All I wanted is to categorize individual URL with regular expressions
Any advise ?

Comment: You probably want `sub`, not `regexpr`

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit this question and include some sample data so I can provide a reproducible example? Feel free to obfuscate some of the URL.

Comment: Your use of `regexpr(...) Else "CatO"` is not correct. When asking questions, please make sure the code you present in the question *actually works*; without that, we have to wonder how the problems we see are so different from what you suggest is happening.

Comment: They only "rewrite" or "overwrite" if you make two assignments to the same column name. If instead you first created a Newcol1 and then used it as an argument to make a Newcol2 then there would be no issue. Not clear what you mean by "to categorize a dozen plus strings to match". Perhaps you mean the question already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541693/can-i-use-an-or-statement-to-indicate-the-pattern-in-stringrs-str-extract-all-f/27541977#27541977